# The information on the number of close votes in Help Center is out of date

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, privileges, help-center

Network-wide Help Center page on [Close Vote privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) says

> You may cast up to 24 close votes per day (50 on Stack Overflow).

This is out of date: Ask Ubuntu, Super User, and Mathematics [also have 50 CVs/day](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13859/increased-number-of-votes-for-closing-questions/13861#comment54820_13861). Instead of updating this page every time another site gets more, perhaps one could say "50 on Stack Overflow and some other high-volume sites"?

(Thanks to lostsock for suggesting *some*)

---

By the way, the same page says

> A closed question can be deleted as early as 48 hours after its initial closure.

which is not exactly true: it can be deleted earlier, if circumstances warrant. I don't see why this sentence is needed there at all. It seems to reassure authors that they have 48 hours prior to possible deletion, which isn't necessarily so.

Comment: "50 on Stack Overflow and some other high volume sites"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The number of close votes per day should now be accurate for whichever site you're viewing that privilege page on. (I turned it into a variable, which eliminates the need for parenthetical comments with caveats about a small subset of sites.)

The point about closed posts being deleted is fine; pretty much the only time we delete posts sooner than that is if they're pure spam, and I don't think it'll surprise anyone that there are slightly different rules for spam posts than for not-spam posts.